# Domain Name Server ip address

Tags: networking, dns

How do I get the IP addresses of all the top level root servers in the Domain
Name System?

Comment: Just for future reference, someone who knows how to get the IPs of the root servers (or even *wants* to know how), already knows what DNS is.  The explanation is noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dig](http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/) to query gTLD and root server addresses with

```
dig ns .
```

or you can query for each gTLD individually like:

```
dig com. NS
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 13 addresses and they are generally included in a configuration file read by the DNS server at start-up.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server